# ember template not update on property variable change

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I try to bind class attribute to a variable created by controller, but when the variable change the template doesn't update accordingly.

This is my a snippet of my template:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li {{bind-attr class="loggedIn:show:hide :dropdown" }}>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>{{#link-to 'profile'}}Profile{{/link-to}}</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Log out</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

The variable is loggedIn, if true show this list, else hide it. The template is called Auth

This is my controller for Auth:

```
App.AuthController =  Ember.Controller.extend({
    loggedIn: false,
    actions: {
        activateProfile: function(state){
            console.log(state);
            this.set('loggedIn', true);
        }
    }
});
```

I have a controller for signin, and it will trigger activateProfile actions within Auth, thus changing the variable and show the `<li>` but somehow it doesn't work as expected.

This is my signin controller.

```
App.SigninController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs:"Auth",
    actions: {
        userQuery: function() {
                //this will be replace with call to the server
                this.get('controllers.Auth').send('activateProfile', true);
        }
    }
});
```

And the route:

```
  this.resource('auth',function(){
      this.resource('profile');
      this.resource('signin');
      this.resource('signup');
  });
```

I try to log on the console and ember property, the loggedIn variable indeed get change, but the `<li>` is not appear. Am I doing it sufficient, if you have better suggestion please teach me.

Thanks

Comment: What is the name of the template file?

Comment: I saved them as .hbs. this is hierarchy of templates folder ~/ember_login/public$ ls templates/
application.hbs  profile.hbs      signup.hbs
auth.hbs         signin.hbs
 ...... Every module has its own file

Comment: My guess is that you think you are using the AuthController, but you are really using a different one.  Use the Ember Debugger and look at the view hierarchy and see what controller is being used.

Comment: I do not think that is the case, because I manually set it to be true in Auth as initialization. Everything work good. What I notice when using ember debugger is that the property originally pick up to be false. when the event occur the variable within the controller was set to be true (I log and it is true), but the one in the template doesn't get update. Any thought?

Comment: Although this doesn't help, I'm facing the same exact issue here. I even tried wrapping `loggedIn` in a property and using that in the view: 

`isChecked: false,    
    checkedValue: function(){
      return isChecked; 
    }.property('isChecked'),` and this doesn't work OOTB. The value is indeed updated when calling this.set from the action, but the template is not updated

Comment: Also, it is possible the value is indeed updated when calling this.set from the action, but the template is not updated, or updates back to the original value for some yet unknown reason

Comment: I answerred my question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question just in case anyone has the same issue.
Instead of having Auth resource, I move the logic to IndexController, and declare loggedIn within IndexController. 
One thing that I notice if you use controller A to change/manipulate the variable of controller B, you might be able to modify its content but the template of controller B doesn't know and update correctly.

In order to solve this you have to use either observer or compute as alias. 
As I mentions I moved the variable to IndexController because it makes more sense that the user status should be known to the whole application and not just Auth module.

Here is how I fixed it.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    loggedIn: false,
    actions:{
        loggedOut : function(){
            this.set('loggedIn', false);
            this.transitionToRoute('Index');
        }
    }
});

App.SigninController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['Index'],
    isLoggingIn : Ember.computed.alias("controllers.Index.loggedIn"),
    actions: {
        userQuery: function() {
            this.set('isLoggingIn',true)
}
});
```

Of course, I moved template of Auth to be Index, but rather than changing the name, that is all I need to do.

Hope it helps!